# Check if target of a shortcut exist in batch or vbs?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, target, shortcut

This is my problem:

1º - I have a original folder with subfolders, full of mp3 files

2º - I have a copy of the original folder.

3º - I've "converted" all the "mp3" files of the copied folder into "lnk" files (With NirCMD CLI tool) maintaining the folders structure.

Now I need to check periodically if the target of every .lnk stills alive or is truncated, because i'm in maintenance everyday with the original folder, moving the files or doing something...

I need something like this:

```
Echo: Corrupted links:

For /F "tokens=*" %%# in ('Dir /B /AD') do (
    Pushd ".\%%#"
    For /F "tokens=*" %%# in ('Dir /B "*.lnk"') do (
        (SHORTCUT_CHECK_PROGRAM_OR_FUNCTION_OR_SOMETHING.EXE) "%%#"
        IF NOT %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (Echo: Target doesn't exist: "%%#")
    )
    POPD
)
```

I've checked the parameters of:

```
mediainfo.exe
nircmd.exe shortcut
shortcut.exe
Vbscripts functions to create shortcuts (i can't find one vbs only for check the target)
```

But i can't find a method to use someone for give me info about the target of a shortcut.

Please, help

PD: I agree too a solution from 3rd party apps :)

PD2: The target of ALL .lnks have this especial latin char "**ú**" (I can convert the char if a solution is for Batch, Other way i don't know how to set the char right)

Thankyou!

**EDIT**:

**Narayanan** i don't know how to use VBA but i give you points for your help, thankyou.

I've remembered that I made a tempfile cleaner in batch years ago and I had the same problem to check taskbar shortcuts and delete them.

I've solved the problem but I did not remember xD

Take this if is helpful for someone:

(the vbs sends a errorlevel code)

PD: The code it's in spanish, but everyone can understand it :)

```
:Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs
::Check invalid shortcuts target.vbs
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo set objlink = objshell.createshortcut(wscript.arguments(0))>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo set objfso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo if objfso.fileexists(objlink.targetpath) then>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo wscript.quit(0)>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo else>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo wscript.quit(1)>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"
echo end if>>"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs"

For /F "Tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /S "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\*.lnk"') do (
    Set archivo="%%a"
    call :comprobar
)
Goto :END

:Comprobar
::::::::::
"%TEMP%\Comprobar_accesos_directos_rotos.vbs" %archivo%

If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    goto:eof
) ELSE (
    Del /Q /F %archivo% >nul 2>&1
    goto:eof
)

:END
pause
```

bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a big pain to do that as no ready made solutions are available to my limited knowledge.

However, you can create a small executable which will return an errorlevel if the link's target is missing. [This](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp) web page explains how to create such a program.